# Iterating through keys and values of dictionaries without staircase like structure

Tags: python

Is there a way, and if so could someone show me how to get the same result in `conf` as the code below, without having to do that long staircase like structure for iterating through both keys and values of the two dictionaries?

```
conf = 0

def dist(instr):
    return {x:instr.count(x)/float(len(instr)) for x in instr}

for k,v in dist("aass").items():
    for x,y in dist("as").items():
        if k == x:
            conf += .5
            if v == y:
                conf +=1
print(conf)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is *matching* keys, just look up the key in the other dictionary:

```
d1 = dist('as')
for k, v in dist('aass').items():
    if k in d1:
        conf += 1.5 if d1[k] == v else .5
```

You could also create the set intersection of the dictionary keys; in Python 2 you'd use the [`dict.viewkeys()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys), in Python 3 the [`dict.keys()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys); they produce a [*dictionany view*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) that acts like a set:

```
d1, d2 = dist('as'), dist('aass')
for k in d1.viewkeys() & d2.viewkeys():  # use d1.keys() & d2.keys() in Py3
    conf += 1.5 if d1[k] == d2[k] else .5
```

Comment: `conf += 1.5 if condition else .5` did not know that was even possible in python. mind blown

Comment: @FakeBrain that's called a conditional expression. :-)

Comment: In this particular case, you could write the conditional expression even more succinctly as `conf += 0.5 + (d1[k] == d2[k])`.  (Not that I'd recommend to do so.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach yeah, no, I'd reject that outright in a code review as being too clever by half ;-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't like the Python syntax for conditional expressions too much, so I always look for ways to avoid it. :)